# Apache - redirect only the domain URL to a subpage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a shared hosting Apache server, and I'm trying to send visitors who come to the main domain URL to a specific page, with the URL replaced and a 303 redirect:

```
example.com
example.com/
```

to

```
example.com/subdirectory/page.html
```

Only the plain domain URL should get redirected, not:

```
example.com/page.html
example.com/otherdirectory
example.com/otherdirectory/
example.com/subdirectory
example.com/subdirectory/
example.com/subdirectory/otherpage.html
example.com/subdirectory/otherdirectory
example.com/subdirectory/otherdirectory/
example.com/subdirectory/otherdirectory/page.html
```

I'm not sure that RewriteEngine is allowed on this server, if there are alternative approaches possible.

The crude way I've thought of is to just use DirectoryIndex to send the visitor to   example.com/index.php -- and have a PHP redirect in that file go where I want. But I'm not sure if this might produce a visible blip for some visitors, or how Google would feel about it.

I've found other instances of this kind of question on Stack Overflow, but the answers are failing for me in some way or another. As the behavior is not intuitive, testing before posting might be advisable.

Thanks

Comment: _“I'm not sure that RewriteEngine is allowed on this server”_ – well then go check that first please. _“As the behavior is not intuitive, testing before posting might be advisable.”_ – yeah, right. Anything else we can do for you …?

Comment: My impression is that some shared hosting blocks RewriteEngine as it can be resource intensive -- and this answer isn't just for me but for other readers of the future as well. Anyway alternative approaches are always interesting.

Comment: Please feel free to respond with your untested syntax producing recursive loops and failing on subdirectories -- so that SO can be filled with more useless answers by "guys who always have an answer to everything" and think SO is a competition to win video game points.

Comment: … says the guy spamming SO with the x-thousandths rewrite question, LOL.

Comment: I'd be grateful if someone could constructively post a link to one of those questions, with an answer that actually works. Or even -- just a thought -- constructive answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `mod_rewrite` is not enabled you can use `mod_alias` based rule like this in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RedirectMatch 303 ^/?$ /subdirectory/page.html
```

**UPDATE:** Equivalent mod_rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?$ /subdirectory/page.html [L,R=303]
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava -- that seems to be working perfectly! Do you think RedirectMatch is preferable to RewriteRule in terms of server load -- or no difference really?

Comment: Actually there is difference in performance but `RewriteRule` provides more features for more complex requirements.

Comment: Good to know to use RedirectMatch if possible.

Comment: I'm actually getting slightly odd behavior in Safari with this. It works fine, unless you manually edit the URL in the browser from "example.com/whatever/" back to "example.com/" and hit the enter key. Then the RedirectMatch still loads the correct page, but the browser URL bar stays just "example.com". Some web users do navigate by editing the URL. I wonder if this also happens in Safari with RewriteRule instead. Could I trouble you to add the equivalent syntax to your answer?

Comment: One small correction, I meant to say above there is NO difference in performance. I will add similar syntax for mod_rewrite.

Comment: Oops -- getting a loop with the mod_rewrite version. "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

Comment: This rule cannot cause looping since it just redirects `^/?$` but if there is some other rule that is redirecting back to `/` then it might be a problem.

Comment: If you open your page in Firebug then it will show you all the requests and their http status coming back to browser.

Comment: Sorry! My syntax typing error, no loop! This version doesn't help for Safari though unfortunately. One last question -- just curious what the "L" in [L,R=303] means?

Comment: L means Last which ends current loop of mod_rewrite.

Comment: You have been very kind to give me so much of your time, anubhava. Thank you again and answer marked accepted. Though we see that grumpy CBroe has voted the question down :) Bye now.